# Showing $\int_0^1 |f(t)|dx \leq \|F\|$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=C[0,1]$ and let $F(x) = \int_0^1 x(t)f(t)dt$

> I am trying to show that, where $f$ is continuous, we have $\|F\|= \int_0^1 |f(t)|dt$.

$\|F\|=\sup_{x\in X,\|x\|_X =1} |F(x)|$ and we have $\|x\|_X = 1\implies \sup_{0\leq t\leq 1} |x(t)|=1$

Hence $\|F\|=\sup_{x\in X,\|x\|_X =1} |F(x)|$
 $$= \sup_{x\in X,\|x\|_X =1} \left|\int_0^1 x(t)f(t)dt\right|$$
$$\leq \sup_{x\in X,\|x\|_X =1} \int_0^1\left| x(t)f(t) \right|dt$$
$$\leq \sup_{x\in X,\|x\|_X =1} \int_0^1| x(t)||f(t)|dt$$
$$\implies \|F\|\leq \int_0^1|f(t)|dt$$

So now we need to show that $\int_0^1 |f(t)|dt \leq \|F\|$, but I am unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s(t)$ be the signum of $f(t)$. Then, $s(t) \, f(t) = |f(t)|$ and $|s(t)|\le1$.

If $s$ **would** belong to $C[0,1]$, we **would** have
$$F(s) = \int_0^1 s(t) \, f(t) \, dt = \int_0^1 |f(t)| \, dt.$$

Now, you can approximate $s$ by functions $s_n$, such that
$$F(s_n) \to \int_0^1 |f(t)| \, dt.$$

Comment: $s_n(x)= \left\{\begin{matrix}nx,&|x|\leq \frac1n\\1,&x\geq \frac1n\\ -1,& x\leq -\frac1n\end{matrix}\right.$ ?

Comment: This is just an approximation of the signum function. If you concatenate it with $f$, you get an approximation of the signum of $f$.